# Correct/best way to return a collection from a REST API

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, playframework, restangular

Ok so here's my dilemma (sorry for the long explanation, just trying to be as clear as I can for this case).

I am working on a RESTful API made with Play Framework. The thing is that I found two possible methods to render a JSON response from Play: renderJSON and renderJSON2.

Let's say I make a GET request to `/students`.

That request should return an array of students - single one or many of them. The thing is in the back-end I end up doing something like this

```
renderJSON(studentList)
```

And `studentList` is a `java.utils.List`. So the JSON I get in the front-end is something like this:

```
{
    paging: {
        total: 2
    }-
    results: [2]
        0:  {
            id: "33333333"
            email: "student1@test.com"
            name: "Bob"
        }-
        1:  {
            id: "444444444"
            email: "student2@test.com"
            name: "Jhon"
        }-
-
}
```

As you can see, what `renderJSON` does here is to put the list of students inside an object that has the "paging" and "results" properties, but results is actually what I want.

Now on the other hand, there's another method called `renderJSON2` which I tested and, in the same case, gives me this result:

```
[1]
    0:  {
        id: "33333333"
        email: "student1@test.com"
        name: "Bob"
    }
[2]
    0:  {
        id: "444444444"
        email: "student2@test.com"
        name: "Jhon"
    }
```

As you can see with this method I get the plain students list as a response, not embedded in another object.

My question arrived when I started to use [Restangular module](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/) in conjunction with AngularJs, because Restangular has specific methods to make API calls that return one single object or a collection of objects. You even get an error from Restangular in your browser's console, when a single object is expected, but a collection is received (and vice versa).

So if I only use `renderJSON()` then I won't be getting the best out of Restangular, as it provides me with a direct way to get and bind a collection of objects to my angularJs model. This makes me think that in the case of API methods that always return collections I should use `renderJSON2`.
The only thing that makes me want to use `renderJSON` is that the "paging" attribute is useful when limiting the results of a response.

What is the best way to deal with this? Should I use `renderJSO`N in all cases and maybe even stop using Restangular or should I use both render methods depending on what the API method returns?
Is there any standard for this?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.

Comment: `results` should be an array, not one big object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use renderJSON and add a response interceptor to Restangular provider to unwrap the received object and store the pagination data:

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/#my-response-is-actually-wrapped-with-some-metadata-how-do-i-get-the-data-in-that-case

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that section in restangular's documentation. I'll give it a look. Thanks in advance!!